# GCC Produced Dlls Not Compatible with Intel Visual Fortran?

Tags: gcc, fortran, intel-fortran

I used gcc to compile a few fortran source files into `*.lib` and `*.dll` on Windows platform, using the latest version of [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) . The gcc used is version 3. The result of the output is `arpack_win32.dll`, `blas_win32.dll` and `lapack_win32.dll`.

I then want to compile [sssimp.f](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/f_src/arpack/sssimp.f90) against the `arpack_win32.dll`, `blas_win32.dll` and `lapack_win32.dll` using [Intel visual fortran compiler for Windows](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/), because `sssimp.f` uses those dlls. But I got the impression ( [from Intel support forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showpost.php?p=107633)) that this is *not* possible.

**Is my impression correct**? Or is it that as long as I can produce the underlying libs and dlls ( no matter in which compiler and how old it is), I can use them as my base libs and dlls, and I can link to them from any, modern or old, compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g77 uses a different ABI than IVF, yes. So unless IVF has some g77/f2c compatibility option it's not going to work.

The easiest solution for you is probably to use IVF to compile the libraries too.

Comment: @janneb, I afraid that the arpack code, written in f77 has some IVF incompatible language constructs in it..

Comment: Be as it may, combining code with incompatible calling conventions is just not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, mixing compilers with different calling conventions is likely to be very difficult.

That answer on the Intel Forum pointed out a version of arpack translated to Fortran 90 -- http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/f_src/arpack/arpack.html -- can you use that?   Also see http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/f_src/lapack/lapack.html and http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/f_src/blas1_s/blas1_s.html

Or Intel Visual Fortran should be able to compile Fortran 77 using suitable compiler options.  What language constructs is it rejecting?

Comment: Not sure about the translated f90 version--- the author himself clarified that the fortran 90 version might be sketchy, incomplete or downright wrong (http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/f_src/f_src.html). As far as I can see, only one or two routines in the whole ARPACK package are translated.

Comment: I read that as "use is your responsibility / risk" -- still worth a try to see if it works for your compiler and produces correct answers for a test case.